# Fabric8 KubernetesClient sends volumeName as empty string for PersistentVolumeClaim causing Forbidden: spec is immutable after creation

Tags: java, kubernetes, yaml, fabric8, persistent-volume-claims

I want to apply the following yaml **multiple times** with the [fabric8 kubernetes-client](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client)

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: my-pvc
spec:
  storageClassName: my-storage-class
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

I apply the yaml using `createOrReplace()`

```java
Config config = new ConfigBuilder()
        .withMasterUrl("https://my-kubernetes-root:6443")
        .withNamespace("my-namespace")
        .withOauthToken(token)
        .withTrustCerts(true)
        .build();

KubernetesClient client = new DefaultKubernetesClient(config);
ClasspathResource resource = new ClasspathResource("my-pvc.yaml");

client.load(resource.getInputStream()).createOrReplace(); // this works
TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(1); // volumeName is dynamically assigned during this period
client.load(resource.getInputStream()).createOrReplace(); // this fails
```

**This works the first time** (when the PVC does not exist in the namespace) **but fails the second time** that `createOrReplace()` is called for the same yaml with the following error

```
io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Failure executing: PUT at: https://my-kubernetes-root:6443/api/v1/namespaces/my-namespace/persistentvolumeclaims/my-pvc. Message: PersistentVolumeClaim "my-pvc" is invalid: spec: Forbidden: spec is immutable after creation except resources.requests for bound claims
  core.PersistentVolumeClaimSpec{
    AccessModes:      []core.PersistentVolumeAccessMode{"ReadWriteMany"},
    Selector:         nil,
    Resources:        core.ResourceRequirements{Requests: core.ResourceList{s"storage": {i: resource.int64Amount{value: 1073741824}, s: "1Gi", Format: "BinarySI"}}},
-   VolumeName:       "",
+   VolumeName:       "pvc-b79ebfcb-d5cb-4450-9f17-d69ec10b8712",
    StorageClassName: &"my-storage-class",
    VolumeMode:       &"Filesystem",
    DataSource:       nil,
  }
```

Notice how **"volumeName" is not present in the yaml** (nil) but in the error message **"volumeName" is changing from empty string** to the dynamically assigned volumeName.

**I can reproduce this exact same behavior using kubectl and empty string for volumeName**

I can `kubectl apply` the following yaml as **many times as I like**

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: my-pvc
spec:
  storageClassName: my-storage-class
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

But if I `kubectl apply` a yaml with volumeName of empty string **it works the first time and fails the second time** (The error message is the same as above)

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: my-pvc
spec:
  storageClassName: my-storage-class
  volumeName: ""
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

How can I get `KubernetesClient` to behave the same as `kubectl apply`? Is there any way that I can apply the same PersistentVolumeClaim yaml multiple times with `KubernetesClient`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround, I have switched to using a `StatefulSet` to manage my `Pod` which allows me to specify [volumeClaimTemplates](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#volume-claim-templates)

eg the following yaml can be applied multiple times:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: web
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  serviceName: "nginx"
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: k8s.gcr.io/nginx-slim:0.8
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: web
        volumeMounts:
        - name: www
          mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: www
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      storageClassName: "my-storage-class"
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
```

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes API doesn't allow you to change some fields for a certain resource type at a certain state. For a PVC, after its state is `Bound`, the `volumeName` field in its spec is immutable; you can't change the volume your PVC is referencing.
When you apply a bare PersistentVolumeClaim manifest like the one in your question (a manifest that has no `volumeName` key or the value of its `volumeName` is nil), If the cluster has a default `StorageClass`, it automatically creates a corresponding `PersistentVolume` object that's the abstraction of your volume in Kubernetes from the underlying storage provider, then assigns its name to your `PersistentVolumeClaim` with the `volumeName` key.

After a `PersistentVolumeClaim` gets bound to a `PersistentVolume` and its `volumeName` field gets populated, you can not edit or patch its `volumeName` field anymore; that's the reason your `kubectl apply` command fails for the second time.
It's now clear that a `Replace` verb is not gonna work for a PVC in `Bound` state. You can `Create` one and edit or `Patch` 'some' of its fields (like increasing the size). I'm not familiar with Java SDK, but it should include some APIs for creating, getting, patching, and deleting a PVC.
You can first check for the existence of your PVC using the `GetNamespacedPersistentVolumeClaim` API; then, if it's not in the cluster, create it using `CreateNamespacedPersistentVolumeClaim` API. Referencing the axiom: "Explicit is better than Implicit."

Comment: Yes, I understand this which is why the volumeName is absent from the yaml so should not be sent in the request to kubernetes. As I've shown above I can apply the yaml via `kubectl apply` as many times as I like (even though the volumeName has been dynamically allocated). I can reproduce the error message via `kubectl` if volumeName is empty string in the yaml. So the question is, why can't fabric8 do the same as `kubectl apply`?

Comment: @lance-java I think that the flaw here is in the SDK's ```createOrReplace()``` API. As I said in the final paragraph, you can first explicitly ```Get``` your PVC using its name and namespace, check for its existence, and if it's not already created, explicitly ```Create``` it. These are the two verbs every Kubernetes client SDK must support.

Comment: If `createOrReplace()` is not the equivalent of `kubectl apply` then I'd like to know which method in `KubernetesClient` is the equivalent of `kubectl apply`. I don't want to write logic to get the existing entity, diff it with the yaml then apply a delta/patch based on the non-null fields. I'd hope `KubernetesClient` would give me the option to invoke the `apply` logic without having to roll-my-own solution

Answer (score 0):

I raised [this issue](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/issues/4332) on the facric8 kubernetes-client codebase and got an interesting response which may do what I want. Please note that I haven't tried yet since I have a workaround using StatefulSet and volumeClaimTemplates (see [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73332617/1089967))

> The problem is the replace operation. It is not a substitute for apply / patch. Instead of createOrReplace you can use the new support for [server side apply](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/master/doc/CHEATSHEET.md#server-side-apply)

And the relevant section from the link

> Server Side Apply Basic usage of server side apply is available via
> Patchable. At it's simplest you just need to call:

```java
client.services().withName("name").patch(PatchContext.of(PatchType.SERVER_SIDE_APPLY), service);
```

> For any create or update. This can be a good alternative to
> using createOrReplace as it is always a single api call and does not
> issue a replace/PUT which can be problematic.
>
> If the resources may be created or modified by something other than a
> fabric8 patch, you will need to force your modifications:

```java
client.services().withName("name").patch(new PatchContext.Builder().withPatchType(PatchType.SERVER_SIDE_APPLY).withForce(true).build(), service);
```